# how to Build SMS Notifications With AngularJS,jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs

i have one doubt. how to write a code for alert messages to mobiles using angularjs. for example if a person was registered some sites then get confirmation alert messages to mobile. how to write for that . please suggest me some documents or provide code. i want to learn that

Comment: visit this, https://www.authy.com/developers/

Comment: And this the npm module you need to include in : https://www.npmjs.com/package/authy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, friend, you have two different ways.
First is - some sms service with api without cross-domain blocking. This is unsecure way and i recommend to do it by Second - programming way. Just do any function, using sms-api of any sms-service into your server-side code and call it from client-side.

From angular - you can use $http service for server-api calling.